# I want to send the class information as a whole in signalR, but is there any way other than serialization?

Tags: three.js

Assuming that you have more complex information than this, is there a good way to send the class information as a whole and use it right away, rather than sending it to another CS through serialization and making it a class again?

It is inconvenient to send it as Json and make it a class again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.